# Gem after successfully running bundle install not available

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, datatables, rubygems, rails-assets

In my RoR project I want to use the DataTables Gem:

https://rails-assets.org/#/components/DataTables

I put the Gem with the right Source in my Gem file and run `bundle install`.

It outputs in green:

```
Installing rails-assets-datatables 1.10.12
```

And at the end:

```
Bundle complete! 66 Gemfile dependencies, 159 gems now installed.
```

No errors appear.

But when I start run run `rails s` I get:

```
Could not find rails-assets-datatables-1.10.12 in any of the sources
```

Any help?

I am using XOS El Capitan. I heard that this can have something to do with the security settings? I am searching for days now without success.

Answer (score 0):

The gem rails-assets-datatabels doesn't seem to exist.
Are you trying to use `datatables-rails`?  [[rubygems]](https://rubygems.org/gems/datatables-rails/versions/1.10.3.0)

Comment: It's actually a project that I did not develop. I am just trying to install it. It's using rails-assets-DataTables from https://rails-assets.org

Comment: your gemfile contains that rails-assets.org source?
`gem 'rails-assets-DataTables', source: 'https://rails-assets.org'`

Comment: source 'https://rails-assets.org' do
  gem 'rails-assets-DataTables'
end

Comment: prepend your source url with `https://` and run `bundle install` again then `rails c`

Comment: it actually is...seems like SO took it out when converting to link

Comment: Have you tried running `bundle exec rails s` instead?

Comment: same error... bundle show rails-assets-datatables also returns the same error

Comment: `bundle install --path vendor/cache`

Comment: all gems where installed to vendor/cache, but problem continues. rails-assets-DataTables-1.10.12.gem is located in vendor/cache. Do I have to specify somewhere where to look for gems?